# Export data to CSV using nzsql

Tags: shell, netezza

I would like to export data as CSV from netezza. The data consists of millions of lines of records. The data should be within inverted commas and should have ^ as delimiter. 
Eg: "a"^"b"^"c"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you want to export data from Netezza, you will want to use its external tables functionality.

If you are exporting to a filesystem mounted locally to the Netezza host, you could use this:

```
CREATE external TABLE '/tmp/test_export.txt' USING (delimiter '^') AS
SELECT *
FROM test_export;
```

If you are connecting to Netezza via JDBC, ODBC, or OLE-DB via tool like Aginity Workbench, and want to export the data locally to your workstation, you could use this:

```
CREATE external TABLE 'c:\test_export.txt' USING (delimiter '^' remotesource odbc) AS
SELECT *
FROM test_export;
```

Unfortunately, there is is no external table option that will allow you to *also* wrap every column in quotation marks.  You will have to do that explicitly with a concatenation in the SQL like this:

```
CREATE external TABLE 'c:\test_export.txt' USING (delimiter '^' remotesource odbc) AS
SELECT  '"' || col1 || '"',
        '"' || col2 || '"'
FROM test_export;
```

You can also use the nzsql CLI interface with the following options to achieve something similar, but it is quite a bit slower.  For example, on my system, using the external table method to export about 2 million rows, which creates an export file about 3.5 GB in size, takes 20 seconds.  With the CLI method it took 3about 180 seconds.

```
nzsql -d DB_NAME -F "^" -t -A -o export.txt  -c "select * from test_export"
```

Comment: Can I use nzsql with -o flag.  Is there any issue if I go with that method

Comment: You can, but it's quite a bit slower.  I'll add that to the answer.