# Unix script for netezza source table

Tags: shell, netezza

In my source netezza table have more number of records.How to get daywise data from netezza as a source table using unix shell script and save this in csv file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export data to CSV using nzsql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706103/export-data-to-csv-using-nzsql)

Comment: i want automation script to get daywise data